# PowerApps form won't submit to SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, managed-metadata, powerapps-forms, patching

I have a SharePoint Online Library in which I am customizing the form with PowerApps.  I added a button to the screen with Submitform(SharePointform1) as the OnSelect.  I keep getting this error: "Network Error when using patch function. The requested operation is invalid".  It's a very basic form, so I'm not patching any values.  I do however have 3 Managed Metadata fields (from Sharepoint).  These fields present as Choice fields, but when you click on a field and search, all the items are there.  So I'm not sure if there's something special I'm supposed to do for the Managed Metadata fields in order to successfully submit this form (again, I'm assuming this has to do with those fields).

I should note that the action the user is taking in this library is to Create a New Doc set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any required/mandatory columns? Make sure you are passing values to required fields and also the data type of Columns and values should be same. I think power apps has limited support for managed metadata fields.

Comment: So it looks like my issue was more with using a PowerApps SP form to create a doc set...rather than those fields being an issue.  So I created a flow that sends an http request to SP, and in turn creates a new doc set in that library on the button click (OnSelect property runs the flow).  BUT, I need those fields also populating.  So I guess to pivot my question, how can I pass metadata from the powerapps form into the new doc set?  Would I add an Update File Properties action to the flow?  The user needs to fill out this "intake form" with about 10 fields, and create the docset in one action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/SUBMIT-METADATA-WITH-FILE-TO-DOCUMENT-LIBRARY/td-p/721166

And: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Retrieve-ID-or-metadata-from-new-file-upload-to-sharepoint/td-p/637388

Try adding an "Update File Properties" action to your flow:

1. Use the `Set` function to capture the metadata from your form fields. Ex. `Set(varDataCardValue, DataCardValue9.Text)`
2. Pass the captured metadata as arguments. `YourFlow.Run(varDataCardValue)`
3. After the "Create new document set" action, add an "Update File Properties" action. Use the ID from the newly created document set and map the metadata fields to the corresponding arguments passed from PowerApps.